# .gitattributes file isn't excluding files from the language statistics

Tags: github, github-linguist

I am currently learning OpenGL and am uploading my program to GitHub. However, because the dependencies are included in the language statistics the statistics are massively inflated.

I have attempted to write a `.gitattributes` file to sort this however I can't get it working. I have gone through github-linguistics documentation and several questions on here and have found nothing that works. I have used the `git check-attr` command and there are no attributes assigned to the files.

The code below is what is in the `.gitattributes` file, and I will also include a link to the repository itself in case that helps.

```
OpenGl[[:space]]Tutorial[[:space]]Project/Dependencies/** linguist-vendored
OpenGl[[:space]]Tutorial[[:space]]Project/glad.c linguist-vendored
```

https://github.com/HDonovan96/Programming

What I expect to be happening is that the 'glad.c' file and every file in 'Dependencies' to be excluded from the language statistics, however they are still all included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing trailing `:` characters in your `[[:space:]]`. Try this instead:

```
OpenGl[[:space:]]Tutorial[[:space:]]Project/Dependencies/** linguist-vendored
OpenGl[[:space:]]Tutorial[[:space:]]Project/glad.c linguist-vendored
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Using `git check-attr` the files seem to of now been tagged, however the language in git still hasn't updated in two weeks. I know this is a low priority job but should it not of worked by now, I am hesitant to mark this as solved until it's updated.